# Maximum of the maximum of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be two uniformly distributed random variables not necessarily independent. What is the maximum of $\mathbb{E}[\mbox{max}(X,Y)]$? Give an example for which this max is attained. For two independent random variables, we can actually compute the expected value to be $\frac{2}{3}.$ But what about in the non-independent case?

Comment: what tools and techniques do you have? Presumably your text/course taught you a way to bound the expected value of the maximum of an arbitrary collection of random variables?  Applying the technique I like here you get a bound for $n$ uniforms of $1 - \frac{1}{2n}$ and in the case of $n=2$ you can show this is met with equality when $Y:= 1-X$.  But you should know these techniques from a text already; it isn't clear what you know here. Alternatively: a more elementary approach is to show that $\mathbb E\big[\max(X,1-X)\big]$ is the max possible via conditioning and working the integral

Comment: Yes, I also had the impression that $\frac{3}{4}$ should be the maximum, but I don't know what techniques you are using to get the bound $1-\frac{1}{2n}$ for the max of $n$ uniformly distributed random variables. Could you mention the method?

Comment: it's derived on pages 126-127 of Ross and Pekoz's book.  I'm not sure whether it has a name.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I got the result now.